# Worklight - How to use IBM Worklight Tabbar API?

Tags: cordova, mobile, tabbar, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I use IBM Worklight Tabbar API to make tabbased mobile application for iPhone and Android platform,

I found the Tabbar API: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_tab_bar_api.html

But, not getting how to start with tabbar in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Getting Started Module for [Common Controls](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_07_1_-_Common_Controls.pdf). Slides 14-19 should help you.

Here's a quick example for iOS:

```
var tb = WL.TabBar;
tb.init();
tb.addItem("0", func1 , "One",  { image : "images/1.png"});
tb.addItem("1", func2 , "Two",  { image : "images/2.png"});
tb.addItem("2", func3, "Three", { image : "images/3.png"});
tb.setVisible(true);
tb.setSelectedItem("0");
```

Make sure `func1`, `func2` and `func3` are functions that are defined previously in your application and the images passed (`1.png`, `2.png` and `3.png`) also exist in your `images` folder. You can get some free icons [here](http://www.glyphish.com/download/glyphish-icons.zip), the main site is [here](http://www.glyphish.com/).

Here's an example of `func1`:

```
var func1 = function () { 
  alert('hello world');
}
```

For Android:

**common/[app].html**

Add the following after the body tag:

```
<div id="AppBody"> </div>
```

**android/js/[app].js**

```
WL.TabBar.setParentDivId("AppBody");
WL.TabBar.init();
WL.TabBar.addItem("item1", function(){ alert("item 1 pressed"); },"item1 title",{
    image: "images/tabicon.png",
    imageSelected : "images/tabicon.png"
});   
WL.TabBar.addItem("item2", function(){ alert("item 2 pressed"); },"item2 title",{
    image: "images/tabicon.png",
    imageSelected : "images/tabicon.png"
});
WL.TabBar.addItem("item3", function(){ alert("item 3 pressed"); },"item3 title",{
    image: "images/tabicon.png",
    imageSelected : "images/tabicon.png"
});
WL.TabBar.addItem("item4", function(){ alert("item 4 pressed"); },"item4 title",{
    image: "images/tabicon.png",
    imageSelected : "images/tabicon.png"
});
WL.TabBar.addItem("item5", function(){ alert("item 5 pressed"); },"item5 title",{
    image: "images/tabicon.png",
    imageSelected : "images/tabicon.png"
});
WL.TabBar.setVisible(true);
```

**android/images/tabicon.png**

Make sure that the images exists in your project.

**Code Sample**

There's a working Worklight Project/Code Sample [here](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/module_07_1_CommonControls.zip) with the correct html, js and images.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :)
and its works for iphone but on android no effect. :(

Comment: Hi [cnandreu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/186909/cnandreu) you have any idea to set android tabbar?

Comment: Android applications typically [don't have a TabBar UI element](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html) like iOS applications. Using the code above should give you an HTML5 TabBar at the top, if I recall correctly. Another option is to look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html).

Comment: Using above code for android I am not getting Tabbar at any place where as in ios it shows, is this possible without using jQuery Mobile?
Is there anything missing specifically for android?

Comment: Thanks [cnandreu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/186909/cnandreu) it's works for android now :)

Comment: You do not have to use WL.TabBar.setParentDivId(parentId) in Android.
By default the tab bar is added to the element with ID content (by default it should be the body).